# Using UCANACCESS with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, ucanaccess

I am setting up a very basic Spring-Boot application, to serve some Access database content as a REST service.

After doing battle with getting the ucanaccess jar included in my classpath, now I'm having trouble getting it to connect to my access db.

My spring.datasource is set like this:

```
spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\Owner\\Documents\\brigette.accdb;showSchema=true;memory=false
spring.datasource.dialect=net.ucanaccess.hibernate.dialect.UCanAccessDialect
```

The error I am getting is:

```
2020-04-08 09:01:28.534  INFO 20740 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-04-08 09:01:28.557  WARN 20740 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\Users\Owner\Documents\brigette.accdb;showSchema=true;memory=false
2020-04-08 09:01:28.563  WARN 20740 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [agency/newmeta/jsis/BackendDbConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2020-04-08 09:01:28.568  INFO 20740 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
```

The access database does exist in that location, but I do get the same error if I use a non-existant db.

```
HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\Users\Owner\Documents\lalala.accdb;showSchema=true;memory=false
```

and also if I use / instead of delimited :

```
HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/Owner/Documents/brigette.accdb;showSchema=true;memory=false
```

What I am missing about setting up the conneciton string?

TIA
Brigette

Comment: You may find [this blog post](https://medium.com/@tobias.strg/accessing-ms-access-with-hibernate-5-and-spring-boot-1b58f26ebb7d) helpful.

Comment: Thank you @GordThompson, it was very helpful.Proof of concept working now.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use another approach: use spring jpa with hibernate.
And follow the article:
[Accessing MS Access with Hibernate 5 and Spring Boot](https://medium.com/@tobias.strg/accessing-ms-access-with-hibernate-5-and-spring-boot-1b58f26ebb7d)

At the end of the day it will guide you to implement a little app to read and update an accdb database.

The important thing to point out is the "patch" included in the source code that  must be used in  your code (without it , your app will never work).
The "patch" is the hibernate dialect: it is very important, it is reported in the source code of the article and shared at the end of the article.